# How to run server-side code programmatically in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need to define some js codes and run them in the server side. I know how to run them thru the mongo shell but I need to do this programmatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some Internet search, I ran into a PHP solution from http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2010/08/getting-started-with-stored-procedures-in-mongodb.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use grails drivers like mongodb/gmongo. For example I use the [MapReduceCommand](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6.3/com/mongodb/MapReduceCommand.html) 
to execute map/reduce command with Javascript syntax.

Enjoy